# How can I tell if the version of Chromium that my browser ships has native support for Wayland?

Tags: chrome, wayland

Previously, I tried migrating to Wayland only to find insufficient support by the apps I use. I know that support for Wayland for Chromium and Google Chrome comes by way of a patchset referred to as the ["Ozone patch set"](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/ozone_overview.md). Is there any way to determine if my version of Chrome has this patch set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update April 2022:

Wayland support has been fully incorporated and is now *enabled by default* in both the official Chrome binary and its open source chromium version. Starting with Chrome/Chromium 98 the `--enable-features=UseOzonePlatform` option needs to be replaced with `--ozone-platform-hint=auto`. You could use `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` as a string to check Wayland support, e.g.

```
strings `which chromium` | grep WAYLAND_DISPLAY
```

### Old Answer (pre v98)

If this command returns something your chromium must support Wayland natively:

```
strings `which chromium` | grep UseOzonePlatform
```

(it will only work with a real chrome binary, not scripts which run chromium).

In which case you can try running it this way:

```
chromium --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

---

### Debian

Debian's `chromium` is a script that wraps the real bin. On Debian you'll want to use

```
strings /usr/lib/chromium/chromium  | grep UseOzonePlatform
```

Comment: My Chromium has "OzonePlatform::Initialize" but that feature is no more, does it still exist? I don't see in the [Chromium source](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/search?q=UseOzonePlatform&type=code)

Comment: The answer has been updated.

Comment: restricting to chromium, I'd have bet --ozone-platform-hint=auto is required since V97 to enable native support

Comment: For me, setting Preferred Ozone platform to Auto in chrome://flags does the trick. Without this, Chromium will use xwayland by default.